# pass javascript variable in soql filter query

Tags: soql, node.js

I am using Nodejs. I am reading a csv file and reading all the Ids and after then i am making a soql query to fetch details as below -

But i dont know why the query is not running.

Is the below written query syntax is wrong as it is not throwing any error.

```
var stream  = fs.createReadStream('./account.csv')
.pipe(csv({headers: true}))
.on('data',function(data){
  var accID = data.ID;
  console.log(accID);
})
    var query = "SELECT Id,Body,Name,ParentId FROM Attachment where ParentId ='" + accID + "'";
    conn.query(query, function(err, result) {
    }
```

Comment: How do you know you're not getting an error or result? You're not logging to the console or anything.

Comment: if i am debugging, it i coming out from the "var query" line... i am unable to print query...

Comment: Well, try adding some debug lines: `conn.query(query, (err, result) => { console.log(err); console.log(result); });`

Comment: still the same case...the debugger is coming out ...it is not printing anything....

Comment: On question if the variable accID contains two ids 0017F00000UNxkCQAT,0017F00000ZSAxR ... How the soql will be written..I think the soql itself is wrong syntax

Comment: I have updated my code in which i am reading csv file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a variable *inside* another function, so its scope is limited. Instead, you need the variable outside the scope to collect the values:

```
var accountIds = [];
var stream  = fs.createReadStream('./account.csv')
.pipe(csv({headers: true}))
.on('data',function(data){
  accountIds.push(data.ID);
});
```

Your query is also not correct in this case, as you need to use IN to specify multiple values:

```
var query = "SELECT Id,Body,Name,ParentId FROM Attachment where ParentId IN ('" + accountIds.join("','")+ "')";
```